# Cons of using a UIView as a Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In a specific view controller I have content that I need placed in the navigation bar that exceeds the maximum height of the navigation bar. From what I understand since iOS 11 the navigation bar's height cannot be extended.

What are the cons of hiding the navigation bar in this view controller and replacing it with a UIView that looks and behaves like a navigation bar? This way I would be able to fit my custom content.

Comment: If using NavigationController you can use its push and pop functions, but if using UIView as navigationbar push pop functions are not available by default.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController gives use a lot of default functionality which helps you in the navigation. But if you want to use the UIView in place of navigationBar then you have to write the whole code for each functionality.

> No such consequences, when you use UIView in place of UINavigationController/Bar.
>   You can see what functionality apple offers you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar